# Implementation of a Stack

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm confused with this `Stack` implementation (ADT). Mainly with adding and removing options, but also by using empty dictionary, instead of empty list.

Here is my problem:

By using an empty list, removing and adding implementations are understandable:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []

    def add(self, item):
        self.elements.append(item)

    def remove(self):
        self.elements.pop()
```

However, I'm confusing such implementations for an empty dictionary:

```
class D:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = {}
        self.index = 0 # since only adding one element per add method
        # better to use indexing for key1, then key2

    def add(self, item):
        # For dictionary better to use
        # self.elements[item] = new_item
        # but in stack we adding one element

        self.elements[item] = self.index
        self.index = item

    def remove(self):
        self.elements.pop(self.index)
```

For this code, I want to create new dictionary after adding two elements:

For instance we `add(7)`, `add(8)` and we get `{7:8}`. But instead, after adding more elements, like `add(9)` and `add(10)`, I got `{7:8}`, `{8:9}`, `{9:10}`.

How do I deal with that? My remove method working fine, but adding seems not great.

Comment: `...I want to create new dictionary after adding two elements.` - your method is **adding** items to an **existing** dictionary, NOT creating a new dictionary.